# Close Excel process by Application.Quit

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I run VBA code in Access and update an existing Excel file.

I have to create xls files for each sales person and update the cells by grouping customer of monthly sales point by exporting data from an Access accdb file which is connected to Oracle database by ODBC driver.

We have about 50 sales persons and will have to create 2 files on each. If I can not fix the problem I will have 100 Excel processes on my PC. It might be frozen when run even if I successfully run the accdb with VBA.

Problems:

1. Can not close Excel process by Application.Quit which I tried to
   open a xls file by Excel.Application.Workbooks object and it seems
   be it's caught the xls file still even I used .Close
   SaveChanges:=True
2. Can not process the VBA code again against same file cause of the
   previous excel file operation process is left which I confirmed it
   on task manager that I have to kill the process manually every time.

I googled on the internet and MSDN site. I could not find any good solution.

```
Option Compare Database

Const TARGET_SHEET = "SalesObjectiveSheet"

Const FILE_CREATION_WORK_FOLDER As String = "Work"
Const DESTINATION_ROOTPATH As String = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop"
Const TARGET_SHEET2 As String = "SalesObjectivesSheet"
Const HEADING_LINE_POSITION As Integer = 3

Public objApp As Excel.Application
Public objBooks As Excel.Workbooks
Public objBook As Excel.Workbook
Public objSheets As Excel.Worksheets
Public objSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Public Sub test200()

    Dim str As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    strSalesName = "SalesName"
    strSalesOffice = "Tokyo"
    strTargetFolder = DESTINATION_ROOTPATH & "\" & FILE_CREATION_WORK_FOLDER
    strTargetFileName = "SalesObjectiveSheet_201708.xlsx"

    strTargetFullPath = strTargetFolder & "\" & strTargetFileName

    Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objBook = objApp.Workbooks.Open(strTargetFullPath)
    Set objSheet = objBook.Worksheets(TARGET_SHEET2)


    If EditObjectSheetHeader(objSheet, objApp, objBook, _
                            objBooks, strSalesName, strSalesOffice, strTargetFileName) = False Then
        GoTo Err_Handler
    End If

Exit_Handler:

    objApp.Quit

    Set objSheet = Nothing
    Set objBooks = Nothing
    Set objApp = Nothing

    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:

'    SysCmd acSysCmdRemoveMeter
    Resume Exit_Handler

End Sub

Function EditObjectSheetHeader(objSheet As Object, objApp As Object, objBook As Object, _
                    objBooks As Object, strSalesName, strSalesOffice, strTargetFileName) As Boolean

    Dim strProcedureName As String
    Dim strMonth As String

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    objSheet.Select
    objSheet.Activate

    strProcedureName = "EditObjectSheetHeader"

    EditObjectSheetHeader = False

    With objSheet.PageSetup
        .CenterHeader = "&14 " & "Month Sales Objectives"
        .RightHeader = "" & Chr(10) & "Sales Office：" & strSalesOffice & "　Name：" & strSalesName
        .CenterFooter = "&P/&N"
        .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$" & HEADING_LINE_POSITION
        .LeftHeader = ""
    End With

Exit_Handler:

        Workbooks(strTargetFileName).Close SaveChanges:=True
                 ' Frozen after I run the VBA code once cause of previous  & _
                         process use same file is existed it seems be.

'        ActiveWorkbook.Close saveChanges:=True
                ' Frozen after I run the VBA code once cause of & _
                            previous process use same file is existed & _
                            (Object and With is not defined error)
'        objBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
                ' Frozen after I run the VBA code once cause of & _
                            previous process use same file is existed & _
                            it seems be.
'        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
                ' Error unknown.
'        ThisWorkbook.Save
                'Error 1004 unknown.

        EditObjectSheetHeader = True

    Exit Function

Err_Handler:

    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9
            Debug.Print strProcedureName, Err.Number, Err.Description
            MsgBox Err.Description & " " & Err.Number, vbOKOnly, strProcedureName
        Case 70
            Debug.Print strProcedureName, Err.Number, Err.Description
            MsgBox Err.Description & " " & Err.Number, vbOKOnly, strProcedureName
            Resume
        Case Else
            Debug.Print strProcedureName, Err.Number, Err.Description
            MsgBox Err.Description & " " & Err.Number, vbExclamation, strProcedureName
    End Select

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Need to release all variable references `objBook As Excel.Workbook`  so `Set objBook = Nothing` when finished.

Comment: @meaden Dear Meaden, It worked! Thank you very much. I'm happy to fix this issue.

Comment: cool, I formalised into answer below.  will you accept please?

Comment: You should change `Workbooks` to `objApp.Workbooks` as well.

Comment: @YowE3K It perfectly fixed now. I tired to run the code again and again. I ran the previous code but It was left the process even It runs once successfully. I ran the code several times and now I can not find excel process in task manager. Thank you very much. Now I have no problem. I can run the code for our sales without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing `objApp.Quit` after releasing references.

```
Set objSheet = Nothing
Set objBooks = Nothing
Set objApp = Nothing

If Not objApp is Nothing Then objApp.Quit
```

Comment: I know this was answered over 3 years ago, but how is it supposed to work when objApp is already Nothing when calling Quit on it (NullReferenceException will be thrown)?

Comment: ok well put an `If Not objApp is Nothing Then ` in front as a guard.

Answer (score 2):

Below line helped, but any other opened xls also will be closed:

```
Shell "taskkill /F /IM EXCEL.EXE /T"
```